# html doctype adds whitespace?

Tags: html, firefox, rendering, xhtml-1.0-strict

can someone please explain to me why having a doctype of

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">`

and

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN">`

render the following block differently under firefox?

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border:1px solid red; margin:0; padding:0;"><img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2010/06/01/1533814/th_park-90x60.jpg" style="border:none; padding:0; margin:0;" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

using 'Transitional', there is no white space below the image, using 'Strict' there is!

2nd question, using strict, is it at all possible to remove this whitespace?

Comment: Is there any hidden whitespace in your file?  (Like spaces at the end of a line?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you can see in [this table](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#handling), the first Doctype [triggers](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/test-quirks.php?doctype=%3C!DOCTYPE+HTML+PUBLIC+%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD+HTML+4.0+Transitional%2F%2FEN%22%3E) quirks mode in all browsers, the [second](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/test-quirks.php?doctype=%3C!DOCTYPE+html+PUBLIC+%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD+XHTML+1.0+Strict%2F%2FEN%22%3E) will trigger standards mode.

The rest of this story is continued at [Images, Tables, and Mysterious Gaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps):

> [Setting images to be blocks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps#Setting_images_to_be_blocks)
>
> The first choice, and one that will
> work for most graphically-intense
> designs, is to convert the image from
> being an inline element to a
> block-level element. Do that, and it
> no longer generates a line box, and so
> the problem goes away-- assuming that
> the image is the only thing that
> occupies that table cell. In the
> simplest case, we might add a style
> like this:
>
> ```
> td img {display: block;}
> ```

Comment: I just found that article as well. +1 for being faster. :)

Comment: so the solution is to add `display:block;` on the image.. amend the answer and i'll give the tick!

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that the white space within the markup (e.g., the newlines and tabs that make the table code nicely legible) are at fault. I've encountered similar issues before, where space in the markup resulted in annoying space on the screen, even where it would appear not to matter (e.g., between `<li>` tags).

Try collapsing the table markup onto a single lengthy line.

Comment: no, i've tested this with no whitespace whatsoever. it's as if the renderer adds the whitespace when using the strict doctype.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the space occurs. As far as a fix goes, if you don't mind explicitly setting a height for your table cell, you can add display:block; and height:60px; to your td styles.

Answer (score 0):

The first DOCTYPE will render your page in [*almost* standards mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Almost_standards_mode):

> "Almost standards" mode rendering matches "standards" mode in all details except for one. The layout of images inside table cells is handled the same way "quirks" mode operates.

The second DOCTYPE will render your page in standards mode.