# Remove "whitespace" between div element

Tags: css, html, whitespace, margin

This is my HTML code

```html
<div id="div1">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><br/>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```css
#div1 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: blue 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
}

#div1 div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: blue 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: none;
}
```

If I insert the `<!DOCTYPE html>` before the `<html>` tag, the page will look like this:

[image]

But if I remove the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag, the 'whitespace' between the two lines will be remove
[image]

But I'd like to use `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag, it's recommend, but I can't find any CSS rule that can remove that whitespace, I have used margin:0;outline:none; etc... but it not work , anyone help me. Thanks!( I'm not good at English ...)

Comment: If you insert the what before the tag?

Comment: Try setting a `line-height` of 30px on `#div1`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The cleanest way to fix this is to apply the `vertical-align: top` property to you CSS rules:

```
#div1 div {
   width:30px;height:30px;
   border:blue 1px solid;
   display:inline-block;
   *display:inline;zoom:1;
   margin:0px;outline:none;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

If you were to add content to your `div`'s, then using either `line-height: 0` or `font-size: 0` would cause problems with your text layout.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/eJqaZ/

### Where This Problem Comes From

This problem can arise when a browser is in "quirks" mode.  In this example, changing the 
doctype from:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Strict//EN">
```

will change how the browser deals with extra whitespace.

In quirks mode, the whitespace is ignored, but preserved in strict mode.

**References:**

[html doctype adds whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953763/html-doctype-adds-whitespace)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps

Comment: Do u have any solution if the inside div's are irregular in height?

Comment: @Dimple If the div's have different heights, then you are looking at a totally different type of problem.  The solution involves using a jQuery plugin known as Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/ If you search for "masonry jquery" on StackOverflow, you will see that this is a common problem, which is why someone created the plugin.  Hope this helps!

Comment: i there any pure css solution?

Comment: This display:inline-block is not helping removing space , instead you can use display:inline-flex

Answer (score 18):

Add `line-height: 0px;` to your parent div

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/majZt/

Answer (score 4):

use `line-height: 0px;`

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pkNys/)**

**The CSS Code:**

```
div{line-height:0;}
```

This will affect generically to all your Div's. If you want your existing parent div only to have no spacing, you can apply the same into it.

Answer (score 4):

You need this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<-- I absolutely don't know why, but go ahead, and add this code snippet to your CSS -->

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

That's it, have fun removing all those white-spaces problems.

Comment: This helped me out with an issue between two divs on the page body, adding that bit of CSS removed the whitespace for me, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You may use line-height on div1 as below:

```
<div id="div1" style="line-height:0px;">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><br/><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

See this:   http://jsfiddle.net/wCpU8/

Answer (score 2):

Although probably not the best method you could add:

```
#div1 {
    ...
    font-size:0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add text in any of the child elements?

Comment: Well it wasn't clear what was inside these divs - but you could always reset it back.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove extra space inside DIv by using below property of CSS in a parent (container) div element

display:inline-flex

[Before Adding dislay:inline-flex;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEZ58.png)

[After Adding display:inline-flex; in css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDMlW.png)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><br/><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div1 {
    width:150px;height:100px;white-space:nowrap;
    line-height: 0px;
    border:blue 1px solid;padding:5px;
}
#div1 div {
    width:30px;height:30px;
    border:blue 1px solid;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;zoom:1;
    margin:0px;outline:none;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TTc23/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Using a `<br/>` for making a new row it's a bad solution from the start.
Make your container #div1 to have a width equal to 3 child-divs.
`<br/>` in my opinion should not be used in other places than paragraphs.

Comment: It depends what else the OP wants to do with the parent container, maybe a background image will fill in the rest of the space.  In this case, I would not fault anyone for hard coding a line break.