# How can I hide a div when content is not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS. Now I have a page with the below code:
**With content displayed** :

```
<div id="row-3" ><!-- Row 3 start here -->

   <div class="groupz_column1" style="margin-right:0px;"><a href="http://www.xyz.in/ads/test.jpg" title=""><h2>null</h2><img align="left" width="100px" height="70px" src="http://www.xyz.in/ads/test.jpg?id=225"><p>Sign off for limited time offer<p></a></div>
   <div class="groupz_column1" style="margin-right:0px;"><a href="http://www.xyz.in/ads/test.jpg" title=""><h2>Test</h2><img align="left" width="100px" height="70px" src="http://www.xyz.in/ads/test.jpg?id=194"><p>A wonderful opportunity <p></a></div>
   <div class="groupz_column1" ></div>
   <div class="groupz_column1" ></div>
   <div class="clear clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

The above code has two contents displayed.
**Without content displayed :**

```
<div id="row-3" ><!-- Row 3 start here -->
   <div class="groupz_column1" ></div>
   <div class="groupz_column1" ></div>
   <div class="groupz_column1" ></div>
   <div class="groupz_column1" ></div>
   <div class="clear clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Now, my problem is I want to hide  if content is not present. I don't want to display `<div id="row-3">` when not even one content is there . How can I do this?

**EDIT**
I did this , still not working

```
   <div id="row-3" style="div:empty { display: none }">
```

Comment: Did you try `display='none'`?

Comment: if there is no content, it will not show anything on your page....why do you want to hide it in the first place then???

Comment: are you dynamically appending the elements in div?

Comment: Alternately, how are you generating your row? If nothing is there, why generate it?

Comment: @Aishvarya `style="display:none"` is not hiding the div

Comment: You can try to append divs using JS. If content is present append it else don't.

Comment: @Terror.Blade Yes...I get the contents dynamically

Comment: @Mayank It shows blank space...which I need to get rid off

Comment: $(".row-3").hide() if no contents found

Comment: @Terror.Blade Sorry, I did not get you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var doHide = true;
   $("#row-3 div").each(function () {
      if ($(this).html() != '') {
          doHide = false;
      }
   });

   if ( doHide ) {
      $("#row-3").hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('div[id^=row-]').each(function () {
    var content = false;
    $(this).find('div').each(function () {
        if (this.innerHTML != '') {
            content = true
        };
    });
    if (!content) {
        this.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do css:

```
 #row-3{
        display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the content length if it greater then zero display it else remove or hide it depned on your condition

```
 var getLength = $("#row_new .groupz_column1").html().trim().length;

    if (getLength == 0) {
        // $("#row_new").remove(); // for remove
        $("#row_new").hide(); // for hide
    }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q337B/3/)**

Answer (score -1):

Considering the comment, add `white-space: nowrap;` to your css for class `groupz_column1`.....it will remove the white space which are appearing in the empty `div`

Additionally, check this link, it has similar issue as yours : [Remove "whitespace" between div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508442/remove-whitespace-between-div-element)

Comment: check the `!doc type` mentioned in the reference link...that might help!