# How to remove space between divs?

Tags: html, css

I would need remove the white space between .

I have tried with margin 0 but with no success.

Any idea how to solve it?

http://jsfiddle.net/554yz/

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: transparent;
            width: 1280px;
            height: 720px;
        }

        #content {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 1280px;
            height: 720px;
            outline: 1px solid red;
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        #bar-header, #bar-footer {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            width: 1280px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: darkgray;
        }
        #bar-header {
            top: 0px;
        }

        #bar-footer {
            top: 690px;
        }
        .content-section {
            background-color: lightgray;
            outline: 1px solid black;
            height: 300px;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function start() {
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body onclick="start();">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="bar-header">Header</div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="content-section">
                <h2>Content 1</h2>
                <a name="section-1"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="content-section">
                <h2>Content 2</h2>
                <a name="section-2"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="content-section">
                <h2>Content 2</h2>
                <a name="section-2"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="content-section">
                <h2>Content 4</h2>
                <a name="section-2"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bar-footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

EDIT:

I have tried also

.content-section {
        background-color: lightgray;
        outline: 1px solid black;
        height: 300px;
        margin-bottom: -20px;
    }

it works, but I rather choose an alternative solution.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508442/remove-whitespace-between-div-element

Comment: You have some issues, try making the window smaller and see what happens to the scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Reset CSS

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/554yz/2/)

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add styling to your `h2` tags inside of the `content-section` div

```
.content-section h2 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.content-section:first-of-type h2 {
    margin-top: 27px;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/554yz/1/)

Comment: For me that messes up the header/footer alignment

Comment: Try my update, the header seems fine but I don't know about the footer.

Comment: Think it's an iPad issue. Even the selected answer has a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to remove the margin of the `h2`.  The easiest way to do this is by removing the `block` nature of the element by making it inline.

```
h2 { display:inline-block; }
```

Another thing you may not need is the `fixed` positioning of your elements.  By keeping your content a static height, you can use the stacking of the block elements to control the positioning.  All you need to do is to manage the `overflow` to hide the content that extends beyond its bounding block.  This may or may not be what you're after, but see the changes below.

- [jsFiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/554yz/10/)
- [Full page example](http://jsfiddle.net/554yz/10/show)

Answer (score 0):

Use Vertical-align:top; for content-section class in your css

```
         .content-section {
             background-color: lightgray;
             outline: 1px solid black;
             height: 300px;
             vertical-align:top;
          }
```