# How do I remove gaps from my division in html?

Tags: html, css

The question must seem pretty basic and is ...

How do I remove these gaps as shown in image??

http://postimg.org/image/qigf1nfen/ 
(Not a very professional img I agree)

I want that the gaps should vanish , like if I want to create a header like in facebook its across the whole page , from left to right , any suggestions?

Code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE=html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <body>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col4">
                    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

main.css:

```
* {
   outline: 1px solid red !important;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row{
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.col1{
    width: 8.33%;
}
.col2{
    width: 16.66%;
}
.col3{
    width: 25%;
}
.col4{
    width: 33.33%;
}
.col5{
    width: 41.66%;
}
.col6{
    width: 50%;
}
.col7{
    width: 58.33%;
}
.col8{
    width: 66.66%;
}
.col9{
    width: 75%;
}
.col10{
    width: 83.33%;
}
.col11{
    width: 91.66%;
}
.col12{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Did you use normalize.css? :) https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Those are the margins of (probably) HTML and Body. You should read about them on Mozilla Developer Network or similar site that covers CSS; they're a very common property in web development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the margin from the body and html element. Better is to use normalize as a starting point (as suggested by @ThomasBormans in the comments)

```
body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Thnx ur method works !! Bt of I apply margin:0 to just my div why doesnt it work?

Comment: because the `<body>` and `<html>` tags both aren't `<div>` tags ;) A div is just another html element, like an `<a>`, `<br>`, `<img>` etc.

Comment: In addition: the gaps you were seeing was becuase the html and body tags have a margin and padding (the size of it, and it's existence as well, depending on the browser). So the div itself, where you have your header, had nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#div1 div {
width:30px;height:30px;
border:blue 1px solid;
display:inline-block;
*display:inline;zoom:1;
margin:0px;outline:none;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Also [Remove "whitespace" between div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508442/remove-whitespace-between-div-element)

Answer (score 0):

You could remove all margins and borders from all elements initially

```
 * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

May you use a **reset.css** to minimize browser differences.

Comment: Thnx ur method works !! Bt of I apply margin:0 to just my div why doesnt it work?

Comment: That's a good question. Inspect your div with *Developer Tools* and see which styles are applied, that affect your `div`. Perhaps `margin: 0 !important` on your *div* overrides the "wrong" style