# Why white space between div's?

Tags: html, css

Doing a simple parallax effect based on [this article](http://codyhouse.co/gem/alternate-fixed-scroll-backgrounds/). I can't understand why there is a blank space between `div`. This forces to adjust with `top`, which is not ideal. See code below:

```css
body, html, main {
  height:100%;
}

.cd-fixed-bg {
 min-height: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}
 
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-1 {
  background:Red;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-2 {
  background:green;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-3 {
  background:blue;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-4 {
  background:yellow;
}

.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-5{
  background:orange;
}
 
.cd-scrolling-bg {
 min-height: 100%;
 background: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styleSO.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
 <main>
   <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-1">
      
   </div> 
    <div class="cd-scrolling-bg cd-color-2" >
   </div> 
   <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-4">
     <h1></h1>
   </div> 
   <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-5">
     <h1></h1>
   </div> 
   <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-2">
     <h1></h1>
   </div> 
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I am forced to do stuff like `top:-73px;` so there is no gap between `div`. I've tried with `margin-top` but it was not successful.

Comment: Could You make a minimal example? There is a lot of code in Your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you talking about "KYIV EVENTS" top space?

Comment: Here is one clean solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508442/remove-whitespace-between-div-element

Comment: hi guys, apologises for earlier code. it was too much and messy. I've added a simplified version. Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is absolutely **not** a whitespace problem, it is a margin problem. It is occurring because the `h1` margins are sticking out of the top of your divs. To fix it, one solution is to apply `overflow: auto` to your divs.

**Live Demo:**

```css
body, html, main {
  height:100%;
}

.cd-fixed-bg {
 min-height: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 overflow: auto;
}
 
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-1 {
  background:Red;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-2 {
  background:green;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-3 {
  background:blue;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-4 {
  background:yellow;
}

.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-5{
  background:orange;
}
 
.cd-scrolling-bg {
 min-height: 100%;
 background: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styleSO.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
 <main>
   <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-1">
      
   </div> 
    <div class="cd-scrolling-bg cd-color-2" >
   </div> 
   <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-4">
     <h1></h1>
   </div> 
   <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-5">
     <h1></h1>
   </div> 
   <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-2">
     <h1></h1>
   </div> 
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is [margin collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Your elements have some `h1` elements at the top, which have some margin by default. hat margin collapses, and the effect is like the margin was added to the `div` instead of the `h1`.

To prevent margin collapse, you can use

1. `display: inline-block`.

   This prevents margin collapse.
2. `width: 100%`.

   By default, inline-blocks have a [shrink-to-fit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) width.

   `width: 100%` makes them cover all the containing block, like a block would do.
3. `vertical-align: middle`.

   By default, elements have `vertical-align: baseline`, which would [add some whitespace below](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17905827/1529630) the inline-blocks.

   Setting `vertical-align` to other values like `top`, `middle` or `bottom` fixes that.

```css
.cd-fixed-bg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
body, html, main {
  height:100%;
}
.cd-fixed-bg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-1 {
  background:Red;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-2 {
  background:green;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-3 {
  background:blue;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-4 {
  background:yellow;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-5{
  background:orange;
}
.cd-scrolling-bg {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-1">
  </div> 
  <div class="cd-scrolling-bg cd-color-2" >
  </div> 
  <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-4">
    <h1></h1>
  </div> 
  <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-5">
    <h1></h1>
  </div> 
  <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-2">
    <h1></h1>
  </div> 
</main>
```

Comment: merci, @Oriol! Indeed, `<h1>` was messing with the margins. I tried yoru suggestion, `display: inline-block`, but it turns out that this messes up the background image display (i don't use plain color). Seems that the suggested `overflow: auto` above fixes the problem without messing with the background image.

Comment: @perettxintxola Yes, both ways work because they create block formatting context roots, but each one has its own problems. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32301823/1529630) for a full list of ways to create BFC roots.

Answer (score 0):

Set font-size to 0 in the parent of the divs and white space now has zero height. Obviously, you will need to reset font-size back to a desirable number for the divs...

```
body, html, main {
  height:100%;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be this way

```css
main div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw; /*optional*/
  overflow: hidden;/*optional*/
}

main div:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

main div:nth-child(2) {
  background: black;
}

main div:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}

main div:nth-child(4) {
  background: orange;
}

main div:nth-child(5) {
  background: green;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styleSO.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
 <main>
   <div></div> 
      <div></div> 
     <div>
       <h1>#H1</h1>
     </div> 
     <div>
       <h1>#H1</h1>
     </div> 
     <div>
       <h1>#H1</h1>
     </div> 
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```