# Removing white space between two sections

Tags: css, html, whitespace, sections

[image]

I have two sections as such:

```
<section id="achievements"> ... </section>
<section id="services"> ... </section>
```

There is a white space coming in between them. While this is not so for the rest of my sections.

I have not set any display property for the sections, but it is inheriting the display property of block from a css file. (on checking from developer tool in Chrome)

I also checked the contents of both the sections if anything is coming out the sections for some reason. This does not seem to be the case.

What is causing this white space and how can I remove it?

PS: Let me know if I should add more information.

PS2: The posts I have checked out on this site talk about removing whitespace from `inline-block` elements.

**Update**

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amit1235813/t9LazuLs/5/) of the relevant part:

```css
/* main */

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.upper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
/* Positioning */

.vertically_centered {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
/* For tagline sections in 5 articles */

.tagline {
  height: 305px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.tagline_text {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.tagline_sub {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #999999;
}
.bottom_line:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #b3b3b3;
  margin: 30px auto 40px;
}
/* row 4: achievements */

#achievements,
#achievements article {
  height: 320px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#experiments {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 320px;
}
#awards {
  background-color: #212121;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 320px;
}
#messages {
  background-color: #262626;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 320px;
}
.results {
  margin: auto;
  height: 35%;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
}
.data_set {
  width: 70%;
}
.number {
  font-size: 42px;
  color: white;
}
.details {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #cccccc;
}
.first_icon_set {
  max-width: 30%;
  height: auto;
}
/* row 5: services */

#services {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  height: 1005px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#services_details {
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}
.services_box {
  background-color: white;
  width: 32%;
  height: 330px;
  margin: 20px 0.66% 0% 0.66%;
  text-align: center;
}
.services_box p {
  padding: 0 15px 0 20px;
}
.icon_set_services {
  width: 60%;
}
#services_details_sub {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999999;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <!-- row 4: achievements -->
  <section class="" id="achievements">
    <article id="experiments" class="left">
      <section class="results vertically_centered">
        <img src="icons/flask.svg" alt="enigma_flask_icon" class="first_icon_set left"></img>
        <div class="data_set upper left">
          <p class="number">1200</p>
          <p class="details">design experiments</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
    <article id="awards" class="left">
      <section class="results vertically_centered">
        <img src="icons/trophy.svg" alt="enigma_trophy_icon" class="first_icon_set left"></img>
        <div class="data_set upper left">
          <p class="number">578</p>
          <p class="details">awards won</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
    <article id="messages" class="left">
      <section class="results vertically_centered">
        <img src="icons/envelope.svg" alt="enigma_trophy_icon" class="first_icon_set left"></img>
        <div class="data_set upper left">
          <p class="number">12489</p>
          <p class="details">messages sent</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </section>

  <!-- Remove white space from top-->
  <!-- row 5: services -->
  <section id="services">
    <article class="tagline">
      <section class="tagline_text vertically_centered">
        <h2 class="upper bottom_line">Our services</h2>
        <p class="tagline_sub">Continuously Creating Daring Digital Solutions</p>
      </section>
    </article>
    <article id="services_details">
      <section class="services_box left">
        <div class="vertically_centered">
          <img src="icons/star.svg" alt="enigma_star_icon" class="icon_set_services"></img>
          <h4 class="upper">Great design</h4>
          <p id="services_details_sub">Our web design team will spend time with our digital marketing team to ensure the core principles of effective websites.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="services_box left">
        <div class="vertically_centered">
          <img src="icons/files.svg" alt="enigma_files_icon" class="icon_set_services"></img>
          <h4 class="upper">Perfect coding</h4>
          <p id="services_details_sub">Our web design team will spend time with our digital marketing team to ensure the core principles of effective websites.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="services_box left">
        <div class="vertically_centered">
          <img src="icons/graph.svg" alt="enigma_graph_icon" class="icon_set_services"></img>
          <h4 class="upper">Marketing</h4>
          <p id="services_details_sub">Our web design team will spend time with our digital marketing team to ensure the core principles of effective websites.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="services_box left">
        <div class="vertically_centered">
          <img src="icons/face.svg" alt="enigma_face_icon" class="icon_set_services"></img>
          <h4 class="upper">Support</h4>
          <p id="services_details_sub">Our web design team will spend time with our digital marketing team to ensure the core principles of effective websites.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="services_box left">
        <div class="vertically_centered">
          <img src="icons/gear.svg" alt="enigma_gear_icon" class="icon_set_services"></img>
          <h4 class="upper">Development</h4>
          <p id="services_details_sub">Our web design team will spend time with our digital marketing team to ensure the core principles of effective websites.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="services_box left">
        <div class="vertically_centered">
          <img src="icons/screen.svg" alt="enigma_screen_icon" class="icon_set_services"></img>
          <h4 class="upper">Web design</h4>
          <p id="services_details_sub">Our web design team will spend time with our digital marketing team to ensure the core principles of effective websites.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Сan you make fiddle? Without your styles it`s difficult to solve problem

Comment: Okay, gimme some time, I will do it. Thank you! :)

Comment: Hard to know what the issue is when you don't show most of the css... But I'm assuming it's a margin or padding issue.

Comment: Remember that you are required to post the code that shows the problem here. A fiddle is OK as long as a minimal example is here, too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508442/remove-whitespace-between-div-element      This might help. Without the code it is impossible identify your problem

Comment: I suspect that you are seeing the effect of collapsing margins.  You probably have a margin set on the element for the "Our Services" header and that is opening up some whitespace between the two `section` elements.

Comment: I have added a Fiddle, please have a look, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the so called [collapsed margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

you need to reset the default `margin` from child `h2`

**Note:**

careful `img` is a self closing tag

```css
/* main */

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.upper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin:0
}
/* Positioning */

.vertically_centered {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
/* For tagline sections in 5 articles */

.tagline {
  height: 305px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.tagline_text {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.tagline_sub {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #999999;
}
.bottom_line:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #b3b3b3;
  margin: 30px auto 40px;
}
/* row 4: achievements */

#achievements,
#achievements article {
  height: 320px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#experiments {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 320px;
}
#awards {
  background-color: #212121;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 320px;
}
#messages {
  background-color: #262626;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 320px;
}
.results {
  margin: auto;
  height: 35%;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
}
.data_set {
  width: 70%;
}
.number {
  font-size: 42px;
  color: white;
}
.details {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #cccccc;
}
.first_icon_set {
  max-width: 30%;
  height: auto;
}
/* row 5: services */

#services {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  height: 1005px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#services_details {
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}
.services_box {
  background-color: white;
  width: 32%;
  height: 330px;
  margin: 20px 0.66% 0% 0.66%;
  text-align: center;
}
.services_box p {
  padding: 0 15px 0 20px;
}
.icon_set_services {
  width: 60%;
}
#services_details_sub {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999999;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <!-- row 4: achievements -->
  <section class="" id="achievements">
    <article id="experiments" class="left">
      <section class="results vertically_centered">
        <img src="icons/flask.svg" alt="enigma_flask_icon" class="first_icon_set left"/>
        <div class="data_set upper left">
          <p class="number">1200</p>
          <p class="details">design experiments</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
    <article id="awards" class="left">
      <section class="results vertically_centered">
        <img src="icons/trophy.svg" alt="enigma_trophy_icon" class="first_icon_set left"/>
        <div class="data_set upper left">
          <p class="number">578</p>
          <p class="details">awards won</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
    <article id="messages" class="left">
      <section class="results vertically_centered">
        <img src="icons/envelope.svg" alt="enigma_trophy_icon" class="first_icon_set left"/>
        <div class="data_set upper left">
          <p class="number">12489</p>
          <p class="details">messages sent</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </section>

  <!-- Remove white space from top-->
  <!-- row 5: services -->
  <section id="services">
    <article class="tagline">
      <section class="tagline_text vertically_centered">
        <h2 class="upper bottom_line">Our services</h2>
        <p class="tagline_sub">Continuously Creating Daring Digital Solutions</p>
      </section>
    </article>
    <article id="services_details">
      <section class="services_box left">
        <div class="vertically_centered">
          <img src="icons/star.svg" alt="enigma_star_icon" class="icon_set_services"/>
          <h4 class="upper">Great design</h4>
          <p id="services_details_sub">Our web design team will spend time with our digital marketing team to ensure the core principles of effective websites.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="services_box left">
        <div class="vertically_centered">
          <img src="icons/files.svg" alt="enigma_files_icon" class="icon_set_services"/>
          <h4 class="upper">Perfect coding</h4>
          <p id="services_details_sub">Our web design team will spend time with our digital marketing team to ensure the core principles of effective websites.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="services_box left">
        <div class="vertically_centered">
          <img src="icons/graph.svg" alt="enigma_graph_icon" class="icon_set_services"/>
          <h4 class="upper">Marketing</h4>
          <p id="services_details_sub">Our web design team will spend time with our digital marketing team to ensure the core principles of effective websites.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="services_box left">
        <div class="vertically_centered">
          <img src="icons/face.svg" alt="enigma_face_icon" class="icon_set_services"/>
          <h4 class="upper">Support</h4>
          <p id="services_details_sub">Our web design team will spend time with our digital marketing team to ensure the core principles of effective websites.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="services_box left">
        <div class="vertically_centered">
          <img src="icons/gear.svg" alt="enigma_gear_icon" class="icon_set_services"/>
          <h4 class="upper">Development</h4>
          <p id="services_details_sub">Our web design team will spend time with our digital marketing team to ensure the core principles of effective websites.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="services_box left">
        <div class="vertically_centered">
          <img src="icons/screen.svg" alt="enigma_screen_icon" class="icon_set_services"/>
          <h4 class="upper">Web design</h4>
          <p id="services_details_sub">Our web design team will spend time with our digital marketing team to ensure the core principles of effective websites.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I was not aware that margins can be inherited too in such a fashion. Looks like I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 3):

That's the `margin` of you `<h2>` in the second `<section>` that's making the gap between your sections.

You may correct it by adding a class to that `<h2>` and set `margin-top: 0;` like this:

html:

```
<h2 class="fix-gap upper bottom_line">Our services</h2>
```

css:

```
.fix-gap {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `margin-(right/left/bottom/top):0px`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **margin:0;** to **h2**

```
.upper {margin:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this: I tested it with the fiddle and it worked.

```
#services {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  height: 1005px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}
```

or you can use this with divs:

```
<div id="first_div">
        ...
    </div><div id="second_div">
        ...
    </div>
```

By putting the divs inline, it removes the space in between elements, because if there is space in between it becomes space in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever come across these problems, the best way to find the solution is by Inspect Element. Here when you do this you will be able to see there is a default margin. So for getting rid of this, go to your CSS file and make the margin: 0; This should help.