# Reduce the space between <hr> and <div>

Tags: html, css, text, line, space

I have some `div` tags and in between I have `hr` tags. There's automatically space between them. I want to reduce it. Please refer the image link below.

[The space pointed by arrow is what I want to reduce]
Also tell me if there's a better way to add lines in below situation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSQlP.jpg

Comment: Probably resolved via a change to the line-height. But post a [mcve] please

Comment: Please post your HTML for that section.

Comment: You may add `margin:0; line-height:0;` (or values which suits you best) to reduce vertical space occupied by hr.

Comment: do you actually need `hr`s? could you not just use a border on a div?  But to answer your question, check to see if the `hr` has top and bottom margin - may be what is causing the spacing

Comment: Try to change the line-height of Text div.

Comment: Please always provide the code and the solutions which you tried. Also, search answers the similar kind of previous questions for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508442/remove-whitespace-between-div-element

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the line height or default padding like this:

```html
<div><h1>Text</h1></div>
<hr>
<div><h1>Text</h1></div>
```

```css
h1,hr{
  line-height: 0;
}
```

[Line height w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp)